# Does each hardware thread have a hardware stack?

Tags: multithreading, hardware

If so, what does a hardware thread do with its hardware stack? My understanding so far is that it may be used to store context information, so a hardware thread's registers can read from and write to their dedicated hardware stack upon a context change.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, "hardware thread" is misleading. "Logical CPU" is a much more descriptive name for the same thing.

Most general purpose CPUs do not have any dedicated hardware stack. They only have a hardware stack *pointer* that holds the virtual address of the top of the stack in the process address space. Each logical CPU in a typical multi-processor system has its own complete set of registers including a stack pointer register. What the CPU does with it is, in a sense, nothing at all. The stack pointer (like every other register) is there for the benefit of the program whose instructions tell the CPU what to do.

In most programming languages, function activation records are stored in a *call stack,* and each thread needs to have its own. In most programming languages, the stack of activation records for any given thread is managed by using the hardware stack pointer of whichever CPU that is running the thread at any given moment.

---

> ...context information...

The *saved context* of a sleeping thread is whatever the OS needs to load into the registers of some CPU in order that the CPU may resume executing the thread's instructions at the same point where the context previously was saved. The saved context typically contains at least the values for the program counter register, the stack pointer register, and some or all of the general purpose registers. (If less than all of them, it's probably because the contents of the rest of the GP registers were pushed onto the stack itself before the context switch.

Comment: Thanks! Your insight guided me to the answer I was looking for: In high-performance architectures like IBM power, logical cores can have dedicated memory to store context information, but in commercial architectures, context information is stored in the main memory.